# replace keyboard with tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, fragment

i know how to build an activtiy with actionbar tab-navigation. But i need to know how to overlay the keyboard with such a fragment-tabhost (for example three different kind of smileys organized in tabs). Any code or tutorial-link would be very appreciated!

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#f6f6f8">


<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewChat" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:divider="@null" android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:clickable="false"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/riwa_in"
        >

 code removed here is a custom view (copyright issue)

<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >



    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addContentChat"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/emo_mod_im_happy" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mesText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.57"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:hint="@string/messageHint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"

            android:typeface="sans" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_holo_light" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null" android:focusable="false" android:scaleType="center"
            />


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just place the fragment at the bottom of the screen and make it overlay anything else?  I can give you a more accurate answer if you post your layout. But for example try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    // Put everything else which is supposed to be in your layout here

    <Fragment
        android:id="@+id/frmBottomOverlay"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.YourBottomOverlayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visible="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then if you want to display the fragment at the bottom you just have to set the visibility of the Fragment to View.VISIBLE programatically.

To hide the keyboard when you display the fragment on the bottom try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: if it overlays everything else, does it also overlay the keyboard? i have edited my questoion includes now xml

Comment: No, you would hide the keyboard when you set the visibility of the fragment to View.VISIBLE. I will edit my answer to include how to hide the keyboard.

Comment: thx i already got the code how to hide keyboard. and i should put that fragment at the top level of my structure as last point?

Comment: If you are asking where to put the Fragment inside the xml layout, put it at the bottom.

Comment: yeah but inside the relativelayout. And when does my fragment trigger the oncreateView method? when i change visibility?

Comment: if you look at my example you see that the relative layout should be the root layout, otherwise this won't work. onCreateView will be triggered when the layout containing the fragment is inflated. Visibility has no influence on when the View is created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34945/discussion-between-matthew-fisher-and-xaver-kapeller)

Comment: Can you post more about this error? Please update your original question with the layout you are currently using.